# Sorting content after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

i have this page:

```
<div class="products">
    <div id="product-1" class="product">
        <a href="#" title="View this" class="product-a">
            <img class="product-img" src="/product.png" alt="Image of this product" /><span class="stilt"></span>
            <div class="product-info">
               <h3 class="product-title"><span>This Product</span></h3>
               <p class="product-price"><span>Product price</span></p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="product-2" class="product">
        <a href="#" title="View this" class="product-a">
            <img class="product-img" src="/product.png" alt="Image of this product" /><span class="stilt"></span>
            <div class="product-info">
               <h3 class="product-title"><span>This Product</span></h3>
               <p class="product-price"><span>Product price</span></p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

i was wondering if there is a way to sort the product-# divs by their .product-info.product-title ascending or descending with javascript, how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I-d use jQuery to catch all product elements and underscore javascript to sort.

```
Products:
<div class="products">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="name">B name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="name">C name</div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="name">A name</div>
    </div>
</div>


<br/>

Sort Products:
    <button id="asc">Ascending</button>
    <button id="desc">Descending</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sortList(dir) {
        var $products = $('.products .product');
        var sorted = _.sortBy($products, function(product){
            return $(product).find('.name').html();
        });
        if (dir == "desc") {
            sorted.reverse();
        }
        $('.products').append($(sorted));
    }

    $('#asc').click(function() {
        sortList('asc');
    });


    $('#desc').click(function() {
        sortList('desc');
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL4dX/3/

Although jQuery and underscore rock together, if you need to load both libraries only for this sorting and nothing else, it would be couple of kb-s of excess code loaded.

Comment: please, merge the answers or pick one ;)

Comment: You need to put the script after the buttons as click events cannot be bound to buttons that do not exist yet. 
If you need to put script before wrap `$(document).ready(function(){ ... sctipt ... });` arond the script. it will delay execution until DOM is loaded.

Comment: Ok thank you, it works! and another question, how do i make it work if products is not a class but a id? if i simply change var `$products = $('.products .product');` to `$products = $('#products .product');` it doesn't work

Comment: You have to change this line too `$('#products').append($(sorted));`
http://jsfiddle.net/jL4dX/4/
and make sure you have only one element with id products on page as id-s are unique.